# Docker swarm starts new containers everyday when computer restarts

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Everytime I restart my computer my application based on docker swarm restart with new containters.

This way many containers are left created and I have to remove them manually.

It seems to use "docker run" instead of "docker start" when the Docker deamon comes up.

Do you know why?

```
.yml
    version: "3"
    services:
      web:
        image: gv/gv-classifier:1.1
        deploy:
          replicas: 2
          resources:
            limits:
              cpus: "0.1"
              memory: 500M
          restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        networks:
          - webnet
    networks:
      webnet:
```

commands used:

```
docker swarm init
docker stack deploy -c gv-brain-classifier.yml gv-brain-classifier-service
```

docker ps -a:

```
ALL SET
mario@moonbase:/mario/prj/unix-utils$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                          NAMES
1142a50966a8        gv/gv-classifier:1.1                        "python3 server.py"      17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes               6006/tcp, 8000/tcp, 8888/tcp   gv-classifier-service_gv-classifier-flowers.1.psghezgnlkoyu7vvptazb2vip
d38e4de74167        gv/gv-classifier:1.1                        "python3 server.py"      17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes               6006/tcp, 8000/tcp, 8888/tcp   gv-classifier-service_gv-classifier-flowers.2.hy4aecfxn3593gohnq1zucz4o
7ab23bfa9b2b        gv/gv-classifier:1.1                        "python3 server.py"      17 minutes ago      Created                     6006/tcp, 8000/tcp, 8888/tcp   gv-classifier-service_gv-classifier-flowers.2.wqk6fsnr0as16mhszy0w8jc9g
0b55bbbd9f40        gv/gv-classifier:1.1                        "python3 server.py"      17 minutes ago      Created                     6006/tcp, 8000/tcp, 8888/tcp   gv-classifier-service_gv-classifier-flowers.1.ixru7unvrr0unbsx3df0bqbhq
6981524d2cf5        gv/gv-classifier:1.1                        "python3 server.py"      17 minutes ago      Created                                                    gv-classifier-service_gv-classifier-flowers.1.tseobtq06m0tbvyias0jv6gyj
1ef783158eee        gv/gv-classifier:1.1                        "python3 server.py"      17 minutes ago      Created                                                    gv-classifier-service_gv-classifier-flowers.1.x7lh5htjkaq7m4a81lmz3n3sa
01ed39f89887        gv/gv-classifier:1.1                        "python3 server.py"      19 hours ago        Exited (137) 17 hours ago                                  gv-classifier-service_gv-classifier-flowers.1.lih7glkexyosgr6zuu0ou36xy
b9b710e119c3        gv/gv-classifier:1.1                        "python3 server.py"      19 hours ago        Created                     6006/tcp, 8000/tcp, 8888/tcp   gv-classifier-service_gv-classifier-flowers.1.2ma8vfxqmekm5pyjxlibpzew4
41b07e9d452f        gv/gv-classifier:1.1                        "python3 server.py"      19 hours ago        Created                     6006/tcp, 8000/tcp, 8888/tcp   gv-classifier-service_gv-classifier-flowers.2.lxdjcugerg8xzvkggh11ou6di
0abcfbc0dc5a        gv/gv-classifier:1.1                        "python3 server.py"      19 hours ago        Created                     6006/tcp, 8000/tcp, 8888/tcp   gv-classifier-service_gv-classifier-flowers.1.klfja0egl5zz1gtw2bshdvgq8
72e69fbfa677        gv/gv-classifier:1.1                        "python3 server.py"      42 hours ago        Created                     6006/tcp, 8000/tcp, 8888/tcp   gv-classifier-service_gv-classifier-flowers.2.q36qvvutbpwr6fyibmbinzq1l
dfe130ed928d        gv/gv-classifier:1.1                        "python3 server.py"      42 hours ago        Created                     6006/tcp, 8000/tcp, 8888/tcp   gv-classifier-service_gv-classifier-flowers.2.uo9vdzu8r50i639shwncyeukt
079a6dd5056d        gv/gv-classifier:1.1                        "python3 server.py"      42 hours ago        Created                     6006/tcp, 8000/tcp, 8888/tcp   gv-classifier-service_gv-classifier-flowers.1.ucjppl7j8vmgttd24lholv5py
...
```